# li data-thumb using image_tag . rails 5

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need this expression but using image_tag otherwise the images are not being displayed in production after Capistrano deployment.

```
<li data-thumb="slide1-thumb.jpg">
  <img src="slide1.jpg" />
</li>
```

I tried something like

```
<li data-thumb="<%= image_tag "slide1-thumb.jpg" %>">
  <%= image_tag "slide1-thumb.jpg" %>
</li>
```

but is not working. any idea? I can't find anything on google.. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `asset_path` to refer an image within your `app/assets/images` path, like:

```
<li data-thumb="<%= asset_path 'slide1-thumb.jpg' %>">
  <%= image_tag 'slide1-thumb.jpg' %>
</li>
```

`image_tag` helper will create an `img` tag inside the `thumb` data attribute, so you can print just the resource needed.